# ionic 3 - storage.get function return null value outside the function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

storage. get function return null value out side the function.
here is my code

```
username:any;

this.storage.get('user').then((value) => {
       this.username = value;
    });

console.log(this.username);

output : undefined;
```

Comment: may you please notice `this.storage` code ?

Comment: what do you mean please explain ?

Comment: i mean where is your `this.storage` definition? do you mean local storage?

Comment: Are you set data of user ....

Comment: this.storage.set('user',detail);

yes i have set data in user

Comment: Its _asynchronous_ because it uses promises.. your console.log is executed before value is returned from db

Comment: @fatemefazli yes i mean localstorage

Comment: @Videsh please check it i solve it.....

Comment: @SurajRao so what is the solution ?

Comment: @Videsh please check the dupe and answers there..

Comment: Also if it is indeed `localStorage` then `then` function would throw error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using function ?
You can simply get the store value with the following code:

```
this.username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

Comment: i want to store array but it provide string

Comment: JSON.parse will convert string to array.

Comment: this is my array 

{
  "user_type": "shipper",
  "name": "testuser",
  "mobile_number": "1234567890",
  "updated_at": "2018-04-04 06:57:42",
  "created_at": "2018-04-04 06:57:42",
  "id": 40
}
localStorage.setItem('user', auth);
first of all i am set the item 
but when i am getting the result this show me the error 

"JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

here is my code for getItem

this.username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(auth));` save the auth data as string not object .

Comment: its working ....thank you so much :)

Comment: most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use local storage:

```
username:any;

this.username = localStorage.getItem('user');

console.log(this.username);
```